# SSIS : OLE DB Destination editor slow to retrieve tables on Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssis

When I use the OLE DB Destination Editor on SSIS to connect to an oracle database, it takes a long time (15-30 minutes) to retrieve the list of tables in the database.

[image: Issue example]

The database is not so big (400 tables and 50 views) and is based on Oracle 12.

I have done some SSIS packages connected to other Oracle databases before and it has never been so long. What can I look at to determine what is the issue and how to solve it ?

Thanks,